# How to find the XPath for outside the tag?

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<div id="fileuploadsuccess" style="font-size: 14px; width: 1086px;" ng-style="{'top':alertStyle+'px','width':alertWidth+'px'}" class="autoAdjustAlert bold animated bounce ng-binding ng-scope alert alert-success" ng-class="{'alert alert-success': alert.type == 'success','alert alert-danger':alert.type == 'danger'}" ng-repeat="alert in alerts">

<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a> 

Instruction successfully added.

</div>
```

I want the text  "Instruction successfully added." alone, When I tried myself its printed like this
x
Instruction successfully added.

Comment: Share relevant HTML

Answer (score 2):

Since there could be some whitespace-nodes as well, I would use:

```
//div[@id='fileuploadsuccess']/a/following-sibling::text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the child node text from the total text as following:

```
entire_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="fileuploadsuccess"]').text
child_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="fileuploadsuccess"]//a[@class="close"]').text

parent_text = entire_text.replace(child_text, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select just the `div` element and ask for it's stringified value, it will concatenate all of the descendant `text()` nodes (which includes the `x` inside of the `<a>` element.

You just want the immediate `text()` children of that `div`:

```
//div[@id='fileuploadsuccess']/text()
```